# How to execute powershell commands via python and giving same results as would be run in terminal?

Tags: python, powershell, terminal, command

Content of my psScript.ps1 file:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
powershell -Command "gp HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 > C:\\temp\\testOut.txt"
```

From terminal: I would run like so, and it produced the correct result:
`powershell C:\\Users\\jnguyen19\\scratchPad\\psScript.ps1`

Output from terminal command, first few lines are:

```
DisplayName                                                                    DisplayVersion     Publisher                    
-----------                                                                         --------------     ---------                    
Windows Driver Package - Plantronics, Inc. (usbser.ntamd64) Ports  (04/21/2009 5.1) 04/21/2009 5.1     Plantronics, Inc.            
Windows Driver Package - Cambridge Silicon Radio (CSRBC) USB  (10/26/2012 2.4.0.0)  10/26/2012 2.4.0.0
```

However, whenever, no matter what i use in Python, Popen, Pipe, Subprocess, os.system, subprocess.run, subprocess.call, subproces.check_output, I would get totally different set of output?

python script:

```
import subprocess, sys

f=open("C:\\temp\\textOut.txt", "w")
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
          "C:\\Users\\jnguyen19\\scratchPad\\psGetAppVersions.ps1"],stdout=f).communicate()
```

output from python script, first few lines:

```
DisplayName                                                                   DisplayVersion   Publisher                                                   
-----------                                                                   --------------   ---------                                                   
Cisco Webex Meetings                                                          40.2.8           Cisco Webex LLC                                             
Carbon Black Sensor                                                           6.2.2.90503      Carbon Black, Inc.
```

Please help, i've spent a few days trying a half a dozen suggested solutions on StackOverflow, with no solution working yet with Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with the 2nd output. Is it just because the DisplayName items are different?

Comment: no, its a completely different set of outcomes.  Its an extended list, but some of the apps are not reported.  Something is not right the way Python is calling the subprocess?

Comment: I wrote a quick script in PERL, and locally tested it, its producing the same bad output.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

## I wrote a small class, that acts as a simple interface to powershell.

You can execute a line of powershell simply by calling a function.

https://github.com/Dustin-dusTir/interactive-powershell-interface

The neat thing, is that my function only returns, when the powershell command has finished, so that you don't have to do any asynchronous code or use signals.
The interface is runs all commands in the same powershell process, so that all your commands run in the same context. With this feature you can
use powershell variables and cli tools, that rely on the current context of the powershell session

#### Usage

```py
from interactive_powershell import InteractivePowershell
ps = InteractivePowershell()
ps.execute_command_and_wait_for_output("ls")
ps.execute_command_and_wait_for_output("ipconfig")
ps.execute_command_and_wait_for_output("$s = 'hello world'")
ps.execute_command_and_wait_for_output("$s") # 'hello world'
```